# add .net framework dependency to nuspec file

Tags: .net, nuget-package, nuspec

I have the following `nuspec` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>Project.Proxy</id>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <title>Project.Proxy</title>
    <authors>Company name</authors>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Proxy component to access a repository.</description>
    <copyright>Copyright 2017</copyright>
    <tags>tag1 tag2</tags>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

With this, I've created the nuget package but when I've tried to install it on another project, I was getting the error:

> Could not install package 'Project.Proxy 0.0.1'. You are trying to
>   install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

So what do I need to add to my `nuspec` file to make it compatible to .net 4.6 projects?

Comment: What is the framework version of the project that the packages is created from?

Comment: the version is 4.6.1. Both projects have this version.

Comment: What is in the nupkg when you open it as it was zip (it is a zip). What folders are there? Is there lib folder? What folder does the lib folder has? Does it have .dll file inside?

Comment: No, there is no lib folder inside, it is "bin/Release/*.dll"

Answer (score -1):

Here is my updated nuspec file which solved my problem. I just needed to add the <files> tag per below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>Project.Proxy</id>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <title>Project.Proxy</title>
    <authors>Company name</authors>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Proxy component to access a repository.</description>
    <copyright>Copyright 2017</copyright>
    <tags>tag1 tag2</tags>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin\Release\*.*" target="lib/net461" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Answer (score -2):

I use:

```
$(SolutionDir)\nuget pack $(ProjectPath) -IncludeReferencedProjects -Prop Configuration=$(ConfigurationName)
```

in my post-build event.

And my package.nuspec is located in main project dir and its content is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <authors>abc</authors>
    <owners>xyz</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>
      Adds marval web api client classes.
    </description>
    <releaseNotes>.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2016</copyright>
    <tags></tags>
    <dependencies>
      <group>
        <dependency id="RestSharp" version="105.2.3"/>
      </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

This generates a package in bin folder of project, a package that works.